# Third hand damages insulation

Tags: soldering, insulation

My third hand damages wires insulation because it's holding them too tight. Any tips how to avoid this?

[image: third hand]

Comment: Put some heat-shrink on the clips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the teeth in heat-shrink tubing or electrical tape. It will still hold just as tightly, but without the teeth, the pressure on the wire being held will be less.

Answer (score 4):

I like to tightly wrap rubber bands around the back of the clips to take some of the pressure off. That way, you can adjust the pressure to your liking. Sometimes I use the alligator clips to hold a pair of cheap soldering heat sink clips and use those to actually hold more delicate components.

See the heat sink clip in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have the same tool; I just bent the teeth on the clips inwards using a pair of pliers.

Comment: If the O.P. goes the heat shrink route, he'll be able to remove the heat shrink and restore the holder to its original state.  Bent teeth are more permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You could also change out the alligator clips for a spring clip instead. I found some small clips similar to this at a hardware store ([http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-3-4-in-Mini-Spring-Clamp-80001/100656782?MERCH=RV-_-RV_nav_plp_rr-1-*-NA-*-100656782-_-N](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-3-4-in-Mini-Spring-Clamp-80001/100656782?MERCH=RV-_-RV_nav_plp_rr-1-_-NA-_-100656782-_-N)). They still squish the insulation a bit, but at least they don't bite into it like an alligator clip does.